# Gluing cylinders together

Tags: manifolds

I was trying to glue two cylinders and then show that the resulting space is a manifold. Here is the first of my attempts:

The cylinders I denote $C_0 = S^1 \times [0,1]$ and $C_1 = S^1 \times [0,1]$. Let $T \subseteq R^3$ be the surface 
$$x = \cos \theta (R + r \cos \phi),$$ 
$$y = \sin \theta ( R + r \cos \phi) ,$$
$$ z = r \sin \phi$$ 
with $\theta, \phi \in [0,2\pi]$ and $S^1 \times [0,1]$ be $(\cos \theta , \sin \theta , \phi) $ with $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, $\phi \in [0, \pi / 2]$.

Let $g: C_0\times \{0\} \cup C_1 \times \{1\} \to T$ be 
$$(\cos \theta, \sin \theta , \phi , n ) \to (\cos ( \pi n + 2\phi)(R+r\cos \theta), \sin (\pi n + 2 \phi)(R + r \cos \theta), r \sin \theta)$$

Then on the disjoint union $C_0 \times \{0\} \cup C_1 \times \{1\}$ I define the equivalence relation $$(\cos s_1, \sin s_1, x_1, n') \sim (\cos s_0, \sin s_0, x_0,n)$$ $$\iff$$ 
$$ ((s_1 = s_0) \land (x_1 = x_0) \land (n=n')) \lor $$
$$ ((s_1 = s_0) \land (x_1 =  0 \land x_0 = \pi / 2) \land (n=0 \land n'=1)) \lor $$
$$((s_1 = s_0) \land (x_1 =  \pi / 2 \land x_0 = 0) \land (n=0 \land n'=1)).  $$

Let $T$ be the surface of the torus in $\mathbb R^3$ and $f: X /\sim \to T$, $[x] \mapsto g(x)$.

Then $f$ is bijective continous and open.

Therefore $T$ and $X/\sim$ are homeomorphic and therefore $X/\sim$ is a manifold.

Does it work like this? And how to show $f$ is open and continous? I tried but failed. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your map $f$. Does $X/ \sim$ denote the two  cylinders glued-together? Then I don't see how you can define $f$ by $[x]\mapsto x$, because $X/ \sim$ and $T$ have a priori nothing to do with each other (one is an abstract topological space, the other a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^3$). Maybe you should work with an explicit parametrization of $T$, e.g. via $\sin$ and $\cos$, and then define your map $f$.

Comment: @NilsMatthes Is it more clear? I edited my question.

Comment: The relation you define isn't an equivalence relation, since it's not reflexive.

Comment: @joriki Thank you, I corrected it.

Comment: Is it okay to also post my result in an answer?

Comment: @user58369: Yes, that's perfectly OK. You can even accept your own answer if you believe it's the best one. You can even post questions already knowing the answer and simultaneously post an answer; there's a checkbox expressly for that purpose (which by the way shows that this is official policy). However, if you already know an answer when you're posting the question but don't post the answer right away, it would be good style to say so in the question.

Comment: No, you didn't correct the equivalence relation; it still doesn't relate any point with $x\ne0$ and $x\ne1$ to itself.

Comment: @joriki I am sorry. I will correct it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to prove that the gluing together of two cylinders is a manifold, you don't need to actually write too many things explicitly in the form of formulas. Even though the question doesn't explicitly state this, I take it from what you tried to do that the gluing occurs along the two circles $S^1\times\{0\}$ and along the circles $S^1\times\{1\}$.

To show that the result is a manifold, you don't explicitly need to know it is a torus (it is useful to realise this, but you won't need it). So, what do you do? First you describe the gluing process as $T=C_0\coprod C_1/\sim$, where $\sim$ identifies all relevant circles. You can do this as you did, but the same result can be obtained by only using two coordinates: one for the height, one for the angle.

When is a topological space a manifold? When it is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, in this case with $n=2$. So, this is what we need to show and we proceed by using the quotient topology on $T$: a set is open in $T$ if its preimage under the projection $\pi: C_0\coprod C_1\to T$ is open, i.e. if it is the disjoint union of an open in $C_0$ and one in $C_1$.

We now choose a point $p$ in $T$ and notice that there are two options:

1) The point `comes from' an interior point in one of the $C_i$, say $C_0$. In that case, the point in $C_0$ has an open neighbourhood $U$ away from the boundary of $C_0$. Moreover, this neighbourhood is a homeomorphism to an open part of $\mathbb{R}^2$. This neighbourhood is an open set in $T$ as well, so gives a local homeomorphism around $p$.

2) The point $p$ comes from the identified boundary points of the cylinders. In this case things get a bit more difficult. We need to find open sets $U_0$, $U_1$ in $C_0$, resp. $C_1$ that correspond on the boundary. There exists homeomorphisms of $U_0$ to an open part of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_{\leq0}$ and of $U_1$ to an open part of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$. These can be put together to form an open part of $\mathbb{R}^2$, homeomorphic to $\pi(U_0\coprod U_1)$.

Parts 1 and 2 together show that local homeomorphisms to $\mathbb{R}^2$ exist and that the glued together cylinders form a manifold. It is however used that cylinders are manifolds with boundary. If you don't know this yet, you could more or less do the same to prove this, gluing together two sides of $[0,1]^2$.

Comment: Thank you!! I have managed to almost prove that the resulting space is a manifold. Can I also post my work in an answer?

Comment: But to show that the resulting space is a manifold one also must show that it is Hausdorff and second countable. (and locally Euclidean)?

Comment: Having a local homeomorphism to some $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the same as being locally Euclidean, so that's exactly what I just did. Knowing the topology, I don't think proving it is Hausdorff will be too much trouble either - it is very similar to constructing the homeomorphisms above. For secound countability, you can look at bases for the topologies on both cylinders - which are second countable since $[0,1]^2$ is. A disjoint union of two countable bases is still countable and I don't think gluing will drastically change that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my work (with explicit formulas of imbeddings):

Let $$ \left ( \begin{array}{c} \cos \theta ( R + r \cos \varphi) \\ \sin \theta ( R + r \cos \varphi ) \\ r \sin \varphi \end{array} \right )$$ where $\theta, \varphi \in [0, 2 \pi]$ be a parametrization of the torus $T \subseteq \mathbb R^3$.

Let $(\cos a, \sin a , b ) $ where $a \in [0,2\pi], b \in [0,\pi / 2]$ be a parametrization of the cylinder $S^1 \times [0,1]$.

On $X = C_0 \sqcup C_1 = \{ (\cos a , \sin a, b , n ) \mid a \in [0,2\pi], b \in [0,\pi / 2], n \in \{0,1\}\}$ define

$$ (\cos a, \sin a, b, n) \sim (\cos a' , \sin a', b', n') \iff 
((a = a') \land (b=b') \land (n=n')) \lor  
((a =a') \land (b=\pi/2) \land b'=0 \land (n=0) \land (n'=1)) \lor
((a =a') \land (b=0) \land b'=\pi/2 \land (n=0) \land (n'=1))$$

Let $f: C_0 \sqcup C_1 \to T$ be the map 
$$ (\cos a , \sin a, b, n) \mapsto \left ( \begin{array}{c} \cos ( \pi n + 2 b)(R + r \cos a) \\
\sin (\pi n + 2 b)(R + r \cos a) \\ r \sin a  \end{array} \right )$$
and define $g: X/\sim \to T$ as $[x] \mapsto f(x)$.

Here $g$ is (1) welldefined, (2) injective (3) surjective, (4) continous and (5) open:

(1) welldefined: Assume $[x]=[y]$ and without loss of generality, $x \in C_0$. For $x \neq y$ this happens in two cases: either 
$$ x = (\cos a, \sin a, 0,0) , y = (\cos a, \sin a, \pi / 2, 1)$$ or
$$ x = (\cos a, \sin a, \pi / 2,0) , y = (\cos a, \sin a, 0, 1)$$
In the first case, 
$$ g([x])=f(x) = \left ( \begin{array}{c} \cos ( \pi \cdot 0 + 2 \cdot 0)(R + r \cos a) \\
\sin (\pi \cdot 0 + 2 \cdot 0)(R + r \cos a) \\ r \sin a  \end{array} \right ) = 
\left ( \begin{array}{c} \cos ( \pi \cdot 1 + 2 \cdot \pi / 2)(R + r \cos a) \\ 
\sin (\pi \cdot 1 + 2 \cdot \pi / 2)(R + r \cos a) \\ r \sin a  \end{array} \right ) = g([y])$$
Similarly in the second case. Hence $g$ is welldefined.

(2) $g$ is injective: Assume $g([x]) = g([y])$ where $x = (\cos \theta_x, \sin \theta_x, \varphi_x,n_x)$ and $y = (\cos \theta_y, \sin \theta_y, \varphi_y,n_y)$. Then $r \sin \theta_x = r \sin \theta_y$ hence $\theta_x = \theta_y$. From this it follows that  $\cos(\pi n_x + 2 \varphi_x ) = \cos(\pi n_y + 2 \varphi_y ) $ and $\sin(\pi n_x + 2 \varphi_x ) = \sin(\pi n_y + 2 \varphi_y ) $. This implies $\pi n_y + 2 \varphi_y  = \pi n_x + 2 \varphi_x $. If $n_x = n_y$ it follows that $\varphi_x = \varphi_y$. If $n_x \neq n_y$, without loss of generality assume $n_x = 0$ and $n_y = 1$. Then $\pi + 2 \varphi_y = 2 \varphi_x$. Since $\varphi_x, \varphi_y \in [0, \pi / 2]$ this implies that $\varphi_y = 0$ and $\varphi_x = \pi / 2$. But then also $[x]=[y]$.

(3) $g$ is surjective: Let $$y =  \left ( \begin{array}{c} \cos ( \pi n + 2 b)(R + r \cos a) \\
\sin (\pi n + 2 b)(R + r \cos a) \\ r \sin a  \end{array} \right ) \in T$$ then for $x =  (\cos a , \sin a, b, n)$, $g([x]) = y$.

(4) $g$ is continous: Let $q : X \to X/\sim$ be the quotient map. Then $q$ is open by the definition of the quotient topology. Hence $g = f \circ q^{-1}$ is continous as the concatenation of two continuous functions.

(5) $g$ is open: $g = f \circ q^{-1}$ and $q$ is open and continous hence $g$ is open $\iff$ $g \circ q = f$ is.

Let $U$ in $X$ be open. Then $U = U_0 \sqcup U_1$ where $U_0, U_1 $ are open and $U_0 \subseteq S^1 \times [0,1] \times \{0\}$ and $U_1 \subseteq S^1 \times [0,1] \times \{1\}$. $f$ restricted to $U_0, U_1$ respectively is the identity map hence open. Then $f(U) = f(U_0) \cup f(U_1) $ is open.

Therefore $g$ is a homeomorphism.